# How to transfer new int value and save previous int value?

Tags: ios

I used

`NSString *level =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Key"];`

But this method may contain only one value.

How to transfer new int value and save previous int value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key can only have one value.

If you want to save a previous value, use a new key.

I'd recommend "`oldKey`" or "`previousKey`" in your user defaults to indicate the previous value. E.G.:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *oldLevel = [defaults stringForKey: @"Key"];
[defaults setObject: oldLevel forKey: @"PreviousKey"];
[defaults setObject: newLevel forKey: @"Key"];
```

Comment: Can I use one integer with different value? Each value has a key. 

           


`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: _index == 0 forKey: @"_index0"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: _index == 1 forKey: @"_index1"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Comment: sure!  no need to do repeated `synchronize` calls between a successive series of writes to user defaults.  Just do it at the very end.